# What is the meaning of "foldin’ your Fruit of the Looms”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

in the quotation below, what the meaning of "foldin’ your Fruit of the Looms” is?

“There’s got to be more to life than sittin’ here watchin’ ‘Days of Our Lives’ and foldin’ your Fruit of the Looms.”

Mama, MAMA’S FAMILY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *"Foldin' your Fruit of the Looms"* here means,

> folding your clothes. (refering to clothes of **"Fruit of the Loom", an American company manufacturing clothes**).

And the whole quotation means,

> There should be something more to life, than sitting here, watching television(‘Days of Our Lives’ program) and folding your clothes.

Answer (score 0):

*Fruit of the Loom* is the brand name of a range of American clothing, so it means, for example, 'folding your shirts' or 'folding your sweaters'.

Comment: Particularly, it means 'folding your underwear' (or what you might call 'knickers' over there). FOTL indeed makes clothing, but they are most famous for their rather plain underwear.

Comment: @J.R. I've only ever encountered their other stuff, but then I don't live there.